# Querying for IUnknown using Marshal.QueryInterface caused FatalExecutionEngineError and crashed QTAgent32.exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, interop

I have a simple test code like this --

```
public void GetHashCodeTest1()
{
    MyComPointer target = new MyComPointer();
    MyComPointerAccessor privateTarget = new MyComPointerAccessor(target);

    privateTarget._pObject = new IntPtr(1);   
    int i = target.GetHashCode();
}
```

to test this --

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (IsEmpty)
            return 0;

        if (_pIUnknown == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Guid iUnknownGuid = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
            Marshal.QueryInterface(_pObject, ref iUnknownGuid, out _pIUnknown); //<--CRASH HERE
        }
        return (int)_pIUnknown;
    }
```

And it crashed at calling Marshal.QueryInterface and caused the FEEE error --

> FatalExecutionEngineError was detected
>
> Message: The runtime has encountered a
>   fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x5ba46832, on thread 0x2354.
>   The error code is 0xc0000005. This
>   error may be a bug in the CLR or in
>   the unsafe or non-verifiable portions
>   of user code. Common sources of this
>   bug include user marshaling errors for
>   COM-interop or PInvoke, which may
>   corrupt the stack.

This only happened when running it in .NET 4.0. The code works just fine in .NET 2.0.

I can fix the problem by replacing

```
Marshal.QueryInterface(_pObject, ref iUnknownGuid, out _pIUnknown);
```

with

```
_pIUnknown = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(_pObject);
```

But I have no idea why. Can someone help explain it?

Comment: The first argument to QueryInterface() must be a pointer to a COM interface.  IntPtr(1) is not a valid pointer.  This can never work, not in 2.0 either.

Comment: This is a test code so IntPtr(1) is passed in for QI. I agree it may not work in real product code but this test code went through in .NET 2.0 without crashing QTAgent32.exe. The same code crashed in 4.0.

Comment: Are you saying VS2010 'fixed' this so it doesn't work any more?

Comment: Well, there were certainly changes in the COM interop plumbing in .NET 4.  The CLR now supports multiple instances of itself in-process, particularly to solve the COM version injection problem.  Yes, feel free to interpret this as a 'fix'.